# cpu load software regulate mac

Tags: cpu, render, blender

I am looking for a software that makes me regulate the cpu load while rendering in blender on a MBP.
On some renders I have the cpu run at 95 % to 99 %.
The temps are in the high 90s. 
I dont care if I wait a couple of minutes longer.
Or do I worry for nothing and this is "normal" behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could handle this.

1. Use an application such as [ATMonitor](http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/), which allows you to `renice` applications/processes to your liking. For example a `niceness` setting of −20 is the highest priority and 19 or 20 is the lowest priority. [[info]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29)
2. If you're more worried about the temperature of your cpu you could also check out [smcFanControl](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol), which can help lower cpu temps significantly by adjusting your fans rpms.

I recommend both apps, and the best part is that they are free.